# Which is faster in SQLite in memory databases: no indexes, loading into an indexed table or building the index after load?

Tags: python, sqlite, memory, indexing

I'm loading a big dataset, about 9Gb into a ":memory:" database using SQLite. Right now, I have a python script that loads the data from .csv files (doing some other stuff on a line by line basis). I then need to do some joins on two big tables. Will indexing the columns I'm joining on make a difference if the database is in-memory? If so, is it better to create the table with an index before loading data into it, or build an index just before the join? And finally, will it make a difference speed-wise if I specify types for the columns?

Comment: Why don't you try this out with some `timeit` trials?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: mainly because it takes a lot of time to test, I was hoping to tap some collective wisdom.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: or not, an index clearly make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing will help: searching through all records of a table
is still slower than looking up in an index with a binary search.

If you create the index before loading the data,
the index has to be updated for every inserted record.

In SQLite, column types do not matter except for
[type affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity).
Having no column types declared will be as fast as having correct types;
you would get the added expense of type conversions only if you managed
to declare wrong types for the columns.

Comment: Will there be a difference between using no types and the correct types?